# Maximum Likelihood Estimators under null hypothesis $H_0: \mu=c\sigma$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio, estimators

I'm trying to derive a likelihood ratio test for a random sample from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ population ($\mathbf{\theta}=[\mu;\sigma]$ are unknown) and this test:

$H_0: \mu=c\sigma, \quad H_1: \mu \neq c\sigma$, where $c$ is a known constant,

I'm a little confused how  to find the restricted maximum likelihood estimators under $H_0$.

Am I correct that $\hat{\sigma}_0=\hat{\mu}/c$, where $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}$ is the unrestricted MLE? What about $\hat{\mu}_0$?

Comment: I think the last sentence is not correct. Why don't you try to write the likelihood replacing $\sigma = \frac{\mu}{c}$ and find the MLE?

Comment: @user3119750 thanks, that did the trick! I was trying to plug it in after taking the derivative to find the MLE, instead of before.